# PHP Reference variable in a class

Tags: php

I am trying to reference a public variable from inside a class.

```
class Settings{
    public $CompanyName = "MyWebsite"; // company name
    public $PageTitle   = "$this->CompanyName - big website"; // E.g. My Big Website
}
```

But this gives back a parse error:

```
Parse error: parse error
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: `"$this->CompanyName - big website"` should be `$this->CompanyName ." - big website"`

Comment: @Dave - No it shouldn't, that'll still produce a parse error, because you can't initialize member variables to anything that is non-static.

Comment: Yeah I just fixed the obvious error didn't even look at the rest tbh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set variable with other variable when defining. Use [__construct](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) for it:

```
class Settings{
    public $CompanyName = "MyWebsite"; // company name
    public $PageTitle; // E.g. My Big Website

    public function __construct(){
        $this->PageTitle = $this->CompanyName." - big website";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can't use $this on the properties, but in the methods, try to define the pagetitle in the `__construct()`;

```
class Settings{
    public $CompanyName = "MyWebsite"; // company name
    public $PageTitle;

    function __construct(){
        $this->PageTitle = "$this->CompanyName - big Website";
    }
}

$settings = new Settings();
echo $settings->PageTitle;
```

outputs: MyWebsite - big Website

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php :

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value

it's not valid.

this is not valid:

```
public $var1 = 'hello ' . 'world';
```

but this is:

```
public $var1 = myConstant;
public $params = array();
```

I'll do it this way :

```
class Settings{
    public $CompanyName;
    public $PageTitle; // E.g. My Big Website

    public function __construct(){
       $this->$CompanyName = 'mywebsite';
       $this->PageTitle = $this->CompanyName." - big website";
   }
}
```